# Not able to correctly filter data using cascading multi select dropdown Syncfusion

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am using multi select dropdown with dependent dropdowns like below
[image]

Populating these list via api. Now if i select one value i am calling (change) function of angular to get the id of the dropdown and then calling a function to change other dropdown values.

```js
OnChangeair(e){
  if(e.element.id=='airid')
  this.filterAirId(this.airIDModel)
  else if(e.element.id=='airlead')
  this.filterLead(this.airLeadModel)
  else if(e.element.id=='airmd')
  this.filterManagingDirector(this.airManagingDirectorModel)
  else if(e.element.id=='airmanager')
  this.filterManager(this.airManagerModel)
  else if(e.element.id=='airaim')
  this.filterAIM(this.airAIMProjectNameModel)
  else if(e.element.id=='airse')
  this.filterServiceArea(this.airServiceAreaModel)
}
```

Function to change the list is

```js
filterAirId(airid){
  if(airid.length == 0){
    this.getAIRData();
  }
  else{
    let finalArr = [];
    airid.forEach((item)=>{
      var name = this.airData.filter( el=>el.AIRID == item );
      this.airData.push.apply(finalArr,name);
  });
  this.airManagingDirectorData=finalArr;
  this.airServiceAreaData = finalArr;
  this.airLeadData = finalArr;
  this.airManagerData = finalArr;
  this.airAIMProjectNameData = finalArr;
  console.log(finalArr);
  }
  //this.assetData = this.assetData.filter((item) => item.AIRID == airid);
}
```

Now this works when i select any one of them others get correctly populated. But when i select another field the previous one's field gets replaced and my change event gets fired continuously resulting in

[image]

Angular HTML

```html
<ejs-multiselect id='airid'  (change)="OnChangeair($event)"  [(value)]="airIDModel" [dataSource]='airIDData' [fields]='airIdFields' [allowFiltering]='true' [placeholder]='airIdPlaceholder'></ejs-multiselect>
<ejs-multiselect id='airmd' (change)="OnChangeair($event)" [(value)]="airManagingDirectorModel" [dataSource]='airManagingDirectorData' [fields]='airManagingDirectorFields' [allowFiltering]='true' [placeholder]='airManagingDirectorPlaceholder'></ejs-multiselect>
```

This picture shows all AIR id but the list keeps on flickering. I think it keeps on changing the list due to the change event.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: how is html binding?

Comment: is there a good reason as to why you using (change)="OnChangeair($event)"  [(value)]="airIDModel" instead of [(ngModel)]="data" (ngModelChange)="dataChanged($event)" ? Does it fix your problem if using ngModel ? Also, you should use === instead of ==

Comment: @AG I tried using (ngModelChange) but for some reason it keeps on firing again and again. It might be because the list changes after filtering.

Comment: Maybe you should try e.stopPropagation() in your onChangeAir()